# Windows 10 Keyboard Lag & inputting text in wrong programs

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lag

Two months ago I bought a new Lenovo C940 with 12 GB RAM and Windows 10 installed. A short time after my purchase, I started having keyboard lag issues now and then.

Without any obvious reason, the input is delayed by around 5-10 seconds and new letters appear only around 1 second after each other (slower than I input them). I also have the issue that when I have typed something and the characters are not shown on screen yet due to the delay and I change to a different program or a different part of the application, the remaining characters will be printed at the new location of the cursor and not where I typed them.

I already tried following **troubleshooting steps:**

- Deleting keyboard drivers and restarting the computer
- As well as the DISM commands shown below
- When there is a keyboard lag, I don't use particular many programs so that the computer should not be overloaded
- This issue has also existed in different versions of Windows 10 (also after the March updates and after changing to the Fast Ring)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19592.1001]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19592.1001

Image Version: 10.0.19592.1001

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

I also run following commands in the command prompt with admin rights:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19592.1001]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19592.1001

Image Version: 10.0.19592.1001

[==========================100.0%==========================] No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19592.1001

Image Version: 10.0.19592.1001

No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19592.1001

Image Version: 10.0.19592.1001

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Each time, I restarted my computer afterwards but the issues came again a few days later.

Which other approaches could I try?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: try to boot into windows safe mode and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, the culprit must be some background process, in that case try to identify with resource monitor if there's a process with unusual high i/o. If the problem persists even in safe mode, with a new PC i'd consider going for warranty, maybe after having consulted Lenovo Tech support. On the C940, there is also a Lenovo Vantage software available which can scan for HW problems.

Comment: Thank you! How can I check for unusual high I/O? Are you referring to the "disk" category in the task manager or is it a different one?

Comment: at the bottom of task manager, click on "open resource monitor".  For an overwiev on functions, check here: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/12/28/a-detailed-windows-resource-monitor-guide/   I'd look for processes with any continuous high activity.

Comment: I imagine tou have tried the windows Hardware and Devices troubleshooter, as explained on pt 2 here: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/4-easy-fixes-for-keyboard-lag-in-windows-10/

Comment: also, try to turn off windows personalisation services which basically saves your type history.  it might be interfering: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/118127-turn-off-inking-typing-personalization-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thank you!

I had already tried the Windows as well as the Lenovo Devices troubleshooter. 
I just turned off the Type history
And next time I incur the keyboard lag, I will try the Resource monitor in the task manager

Comment: @1NN I found the resource monitor. However, I do not see an I/O section, where would that be?

Comment: one more idea before resource monitor: have you checked the settings in:  Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Set up Filter Keys (you can actually paste that string into the search bar of control panel)

Comment: Keep open resource bonitor beside some window you can type in. First, keep open the overview tab. While you are experienccing the keyboard lag, see if any of the CPU or Disk or Memory or Network graphs is at maximum. If yes, search on the relative tab for the process who is maxing out your resources. See what software or service that process belongs to. Try to stop that service (in task manager -> Services tab) or uninstall that software. If none of your resources are being maxed out ... I'm at loss ..

Comment: also, if you have any external USB-keyboard lying around, try to connect that and see if the behaviour changes. Like this, you can test for possible hardware (or driver?) errors on your built-in keyboard